# Simplifying this inequality with orthonormality relation

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to simplify the following inequality

\begin{equation}
\langle (a_0e_0+a_1e_1)|a_0e_0 +a_1e_1|^2, \overline{e}_1\rangle
\end{equation}

where $a_ie_i$ are eigenvalue-eigenfunction pairs, and we use the $L^2$ inner product. Both $a_i$ and $e_i$ are complex and the orthogonality relation is such that $\langle e_i, \tilde{e}_j \rangle  = \delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. It is that the eigenfunctions depend only on space, and that the eigenvalues depend only on time.

Also, with regard to the $L_2$ norm, I also want to know how to show that

\begin{equation}
\| (|u| |v| w )\|_{L^2}  \leq \|u\|_{L^2} \| v \|_{L^2} \|w\|_{L^2} 
\end{equation} for all $u,v,w \in H^1_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}) \cap H^2( \mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$.

Any resources as to whether this is possible for the nonlinearity for the Navier-Stokes flow would be appreciated! I feel as though I need a crash course in inequalities!

Kindest regards,

Catherine

Comment: Are you using the convention of linearity in the second position of the inner product, or the first position?

Comment: Also, is $\|(|u| |v|w)\|_{L^2}$ meant to be an inner product? If so, where is the comma supposed to be?

Comment: So the inner product in this case is $\langle f, g \rangle = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} f g^* dx$. Therefore the $L^2$ norm is given by $||u||_{L_2}= \langle u, u \rangle ^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Right, so you're linear in the first argument, not the second. Can you please clarify the expression $\|(|u| |v|w)\|_{L^2}$?

Comment: So it essentially the same as $|u|^2 u$, just with three different components to show what the cubic mapping does. I really just want to know whether or not $|| |u|^2 u ||_{L^2} \leq ||u||_{L^2} ||u||_{L^2} ||u||_{L^2} $.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: by the expression $|a_0e_0+a_1e_1|^2$, do you mean to have taken a norm there, or is it just the square of the modulus, and the result is still a function?

Comment: So this is equal to $(a_0e_0  + a_1 e_1)(a_0e_0 + a_1e_1)^*$ where the * is the complex conjugate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76506/discussion-between-catherine-drysdale-and-adrian-keister).

Answer (score 0):

You can do
\begin{align*}
\langle (a_0e_0+a_1e_1)|a_0e_0 +a_1e_1|^2, \overline{e}_1\rangle&=
\left[\langle a_0e_0|a_0e_0 +a_1e_1|^2, \overline{e}_1\rangle+\langle a_1e_1|a_0e_0 +a_1e_1|^2,\overline{e}_1\rangle\right]\\
&=\left[a_0\langle e_0|a_0e_0 +a_1e_1|^2, \overline{e}_1\rangle+a_1\langle e_1|a_0e_0 +a_1e_1|^2,\overline{e}_1\rangle\right],
\end{align*}
but I think that's as far as you can go. Alternatively, you could try to write out $|a_0e_0+a_1e_1|^2=(a_0e_0+a_1e_1)(\overline{a}_0\overline{e}_0+\overline{a}_1\overline{e}_1),$ but it's not clear where that would lead you. It is not the case that $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ implies $\langle e_i,\overline{e}_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$. Moreover, all integrals in sight have four functions multiplied together inside! It would be impossible to use orthogonality to simplify any of them.

[EDIT] Reevaluating the following reasoning...

For your inequality there, you can simply apply Cauchy-Schwarz twice:
$$\|uvw\|\le \|u\| \|vw\|\le \|u\| \|v\| \|w\|$$

Comment: I am so sorry; I made a mistake in the question. It is $ \langle e_i, \tilde{e}_j\rangle = \delta_{ij] $, and not the previous case! I have edited it now.

Comment: I still don't think you're going to have any simplifications possible. You still have four functions inside each integral. To use orthogonality, you need to have only two functions inside.

Comment: Okay, can you explain a little bit more about the Cauchy Swartz? Are they all L^2 norms? xx

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz states that $|\langle u,v\rangle|\le\|u\| \|v\|$. Here the inner product is the $L^2$ inner product, and the norms are the $L^2$ norm defined by $\|u\|=\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}$, which uses the $L^2$ inner product. Now that I'm thinking about this, my reasoning doesn't look correct. The problem is that you've got ordinary multiplication inside the LHS norm, which is not really what C-S covers. Let me think about it some more...